# Get JavaScript Geolocation of Hosting Device

Tags: javascript, node.js, geolocation

I want the immense accuracy of coordinates returned with `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` but instead of the *client machine's location*, I want the *hosting machine's*.  Any IP-based solution I have found is *sorely* lacking in exactness (to be expected).

Envision a **"Find My iPhone"**-type of service but for any device.  You visit a certain URL where you are able to see wherever whatever on which you have placed this technology goes.  Is there a way to expose such (I imagine low-level) information if I'm developing with **Node.js** or otherwise?  Thanks!

Comment: in case you haven't found prey yet, here's the link: http://preyproject.com/

Answer (score 0):

Host machines are just computers running some server software; they don't necessarily know where they are. You could save location data on a specific server for a client to access, but there's no way (besides guessing based on the IP like you mentioned) that a client can figure out where a given server is physically located if the server doesn't tell it.

Comment: I'm thinking there's gotta be a way if the server is on a machine with WiFi and/or GPS capabilities.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: Wait, are you talking about getting the location only of servers you have access to?

Comment: Yes.  Instead of the "Share Location" in modern browsers which merely pinpoints the client machine's location (like an iPhone), I am trying to triangulate the machine whose server is being accessed.